# How to overwrite this.href in the beforeShow block? (jquery / fancybox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to overwrite `this.href` in the `beforeShow` block but it doesn't work.
The old value of `this.href` is being used even if it's overwritten.

Code is:

```
beforeShow: function (opts, fb_obj) {

    // this conditional is some other code checking $(window).width() and $(window).height() and
    // if the bigger image will fit; it is simplified here!
    if (1) {
        var source = this.href;
        this.href = source.replace('_large','_super_large');
        console.log('retina detacted! ' + source + " " + this.href);
        // console output is OK, but this.href is not beeing replaced in the output!
}
```

Comment: This will not effect, because the content has already been loaded. Use `beforeLoad` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the value of `this.href`, use `beforeLoad` instead.

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this in jquery ..ill say

The full code

```
if (1) {
         var oldhref = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href','_super_large');
        console.log('retina detacted! ' +oldhref + " " + this.attr('href');
}
```

Comment: retina detacted! images/uploads/_large/0240.jpg images/uploads/_super_large/0240.jpg